# How do I add <<flow>> underneath arrow?

Tags: visio

I'm attempting to create an information flow diagram using the format found here:

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/information-flow-elements.html

The problem is I am unable to figure out how to put the name of the flow above the arrow and the << flow >> below the arrow. The only arrows I can find like on the website are dependency arrows and when I name the information flow, the name goes through the arrow not above it.

While the arrows found in the UML USE Case shapes have the << >>, it does not have a << flow >> and will not allow me to add it.

Answer (score 0):

To do the above you must first download a UML 2.2 stencil and template from:

http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/#Visio2010

From there you click and drag the Message (seq.diag) line and place it where you want. Double-click on the arrow, and add the text that will be above the arrow. Then right-click on the arrow, go to format, then click on line to open the line box.  Pick the dash type you want.  That takes care of the line and arrow.

To get the << flow >> stereotype, click on the Label and place it underneath the arrow.  Double click on it and add << flow >>